# In the Hangouts app, how do I "mark all as read"?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

I'm using Hangouts for texting with my Samsung Galaxy S4. Usually the preview is enough to see the whole message. I hate having to open a message just to mark it a read. Is there a way to mark one, or several, or all messages as read without opening the message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunate that this question had never received any love. Despite it being an entire year later, this functionality is not available as a feature in the Hangouts app on Android, iOS, or the web.

Here is the most relevant discussion from the [Google Hangouts Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/hangouts/LLcDSZPZviw)

> Thank you for your feedback!
>   Yes you are right, there isn't such a button yet. I think Hangouts wants to make sure that you really have read the messages without missing any information.
>   However, I'll move your topic to the idea section for the team to consider it as a feature request.
>   *Nick Ross*

Comment: This might be more relevant now [Hangouts is going away](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/ras-Y5TGI40)